# How to get and set correct current path

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, foundation

in my simple command line program, I try to write a string into a text file,

```
[str writeToFile:@"myfile.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

when I run my exec file via finder, I expect "myfile.txt" be created in the same folder that exec file is, but it was made in "/users/me"

later I tried to get current path of my program via these codes

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *currentpath;
filemgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];
NSLog(@"Current path is : %@",current path);
```

and I found out that regardless of the location of my exec file, the current path always is "/users/me".  is there any way to get correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the instance returned from the `defaultManager` method of `NSFileManager` to manipulate your current path:

```
NSString *currentpath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath];
```

or

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] changeCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/new/path/"];
```

You can get the path of your executable from the `bundlePath` method of the bundle:

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```